# How to transform the output regarding exponentiation?

Tags: syntax

everybody! I use Wolfram, among other things, to create formulas, which I then use in C# code. The syntax of C# and Wolfram differ from each other, so I'm just rewriting the resulting idea from Wolfram to C#. But some of the expressions I receive are very cumbersome and it is simply impossible to rewrite them manually. In particular, the main difficulty is the difference in exponentiation (in C# Math.Pow(x, y), where y is the degree). I wrote a little function, that works like this: `(2 x + 5^y - 4) /.x_^y_ :> "Math.Pow(" <> ToString@x <> ", " <> ToString@y <> ")"`. It works well and gets `-4 + "Math.Pow(5, y)" + 2 x`. But look at this: `(2 x + 5^y - 4)^3 /. x_^y_ :> "Math.Pow(" <> ToString@x <> ", " <> ToString@y <> ")"` that gets "Math.Pow(      y
-4 + 5  + 2 x, 3)". Can you please help me with this task? How should this code be written to "eat" large and sophisticated expressions without getting rubbish? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use [`CForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm.html) to do the heavy lifting, followed by `StringReplace` to apply the final tweaks (e.g. renaming functions to match the C# syntax):

```
StringReplace[ToString@CForm[(2x+5^y-4)^3],"Power"->"Math.Pow"] 
(* Math.Pow(-4 + Math.Pow(5,y) + 2*x,3) *)
```

If you want to get something like `a[2][3]`, the easiest way is to use `Part` in the original expression, since that is already handled correctly:

```
CForm[a[[2, 3]]]
(* Part::partd: Part specification a[[2,3]] is longer than depth of object. *)
(* a[2][3] *)
```

As a more complete example:

```
expr = (2 Subscript[Abx, 2, 3] + 5^y - 4)^3;
StringReplace[
 ToString@CForm[
   HoldForm@Evaluate[
     expr /. Subscript -> MapAt[#-1&, 2;;] @* Subscript
    ] /. {
       Subscript -> Part,
       Abx -> ax
     }
   ],
 "Power" -> "Math.Pow"
 ]
(* Math.Pow(-4 + Math.Pow(5,y) + 2*ax[1][2],3) *)
```

As you can see, we simply replace `Subscript` with `Part` to get the desired formatting. The `HoldForm@Evaluate@...` wrapper is just there to prevent `Part` from generating warning messages. To change from 1-indexing to 0-indexing, we first use `MapAt` to reduce all indices by 1. (we keep `Subscript` at this stage to more easily supress the messages)

Comment: Thank you, it does work! Can we use the same or the other way replace expressions like Subscript[Abx, 5, 3] (or in my expression after your transformation it looks like Subscript(Abx,5,3)) with a[4][2]? I mean each Abx should be just ax, and every "index" n in Subscript function should be n - 1. Is this possible?

Comment: @АлександрМиллер See the update